# Using a While loop in python when asking for something specific

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Question is to
Prompt the user for a number from 1 to 100. Using a while loop, if they entered an invalid number, tell them the number entered is invalid and then prompt them again for a number from 1 to 100. If they enter a valid number - thank them for their input.

```
x = int(input("please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: "))
y = x<0 or x>100 

while y is True: 
  print("invalid.")
  int(input("please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: ")
else:
  print("thank you for your input")
```

my code is incorrect. Help me fix it please?

Comment: Amm but the error does not match the code at all. There isn't any `continue` in your code...

Comment: give the code not the image of code

Comment: im quite new to this. where would i add a continue to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplification and correction of your code

```
while True:
    x = int(input("please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: "))
    if 1 <= x <= 100:      # range check
        print("thank you for your input")
        break              # terminates while loop
    else:
        print("invalid.")  # print then continue in while loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you missing a parenthesis in the statement before else: ? Looks like it says else: is invalid due to that.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the syntax error (missing `)` before the line of `else`, your code also have logical error, you need to set the `y = False` when user give proper input to get out from the `while` loop, like :

```
x = int(input("please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: "))
y = x<0 or x>100 

while y is True: 
  print("invalid.")
  value = int(input("please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: "))
  if value >= 0 and value <= 100:
      y = False
else:
  print("thank you for your input")
```

Answer (score 0):

@Krish says a really good answer about how you are missing a second bracket during the line that you prompt inside the while loop. I assume you receive a `SyntaxError` about it (probably listing the immediately following line--unfortunately common in software).

### Solution

However, you have a much more fundamental issue with your code: you never update `y` so you have an infinite loop that will always think that the input is invalid.

```py
x = int(input("please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: "))
y = x<0 or x>100 

while y: # it is unnecessary to check a boolean against a condition 
  print("invalid.")
  x = int(input("please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: ")) # missing bracket
  y = x<0 or x>100 # necessary to end the loop
else:
  print("thank you for your input")
```

### Improvement

Another option is to use `break` to exit the loop on the spot. It can make for cleaner code with less duplication because now everything is inside the loop.

```py
while True: # infinite loop...but not because of break
  x = int(input("please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: "))
  if x<0 or x>100:
    print("invalid.")
  else:
    print("thank you for your input")
    break
```

### Advanced

For completeness I will also include a couple more advanced features. You can skip this part since you are starting out, but it may be interesting to come back to once you have become more familiar with the language.

#### Lambda

Helps make the code cleaner.

```py
user_input = lambda: int(input("please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: "))
condition = lambda x: x<0 or x>100
while condition(user_input()):
  print("invalid.")
else:
  print("thank you for your input")
```

#### Cmd

This one is really advanced and overkill for what you are trying to accomplish. Still, it is good to know about for a later, more advanced problem that it would be appropriate for. Docs found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html).

```py
from cmd import Cmd

class ValidNumberPrompter(Cmd):
  """
  This is a class for a CLI to prompt users for a valid number.
  """
  prompt = "please enter a number 1-100, inclusive: "
  def parseline(self, line): # normally would override precmd but this is modifying the way the line is parsed for commands later
    command, args, line = super().parseline(line) # superclass behaviour
    return (command, args, int(line))
  def default(self, line): # don't care about commands
    if line<0 or line>100:
      print("invalid.")
      return False
    else:
      print("thank you for your input")
      return True

"""
Only start if module is being run at the cmdline.
If it is being imported, let the caller decide
what to do and when to run it.
"""
if __name__ = '__main__':
  ValidNumberPrompter().cmdloop()
```